# Редактирование вложенного массива, как найти его "индекс" или что-то вроде того?

Tags: php

Есть массив такого типа.

```
$targetsArray = array(
    array("UserID" => "10", "DetectedAt" => "1608437336", "Step" => "0", "Result" => "0"),
    array("UserID" => "11", "DetectedAt" => "1608437642", "Step" => "0", "Result" => "2"),
    array("UserID" => "12", "DetectedAt" => "1608495221", "Step" => "1", "Result" => "0"),
    array("UserID" => "16", "DetectedAt" => "1608499765", "Step" => "0", "Result" => "0")
);
```

Каким методом, я могу редактировать вложенный массив допустим, например как MySQL.
Нужен аналог для PHP, что-то типо:

```
"UPDATE `targetsArray` SET `Step`=2 WHERE `UserID`=16
```

Ну, я думаю вы поняли, как в PHP так сделать? Как изменить переменную во вложенном массиве?

Я понимаю, что это легко сделать, в базовом массиве типо

```
$arr = array(1234,6345,53443);
$arr[1] = 634; //тут мне известен индекс допустим, а во вложенном неизвестен так сказать

$arr = array('Step' => 1, 'Somevar' => 0);
$arr['Step'] = 0; //тут тоже легко
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Додумался.

Можно так редактировать:

```
$targetsArray[1]['Step'] = 524324;
```